# How to parse JSON from python service with unicode? SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Tags: python, json, angularjs, unicode, google-bigquery

I'm loading json from http://pythond3jsmashup.appspot.com/chart using angular js

```
$http.get('http://pythond3jsmashup.appspot.com/chart');
```

I got this service from a an example of how to get Google BigQuery data as a service using python  (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/data-visualization-app-using-gae-python-d3js-and-google-bigquery--cms-22175).

Angular has a problem with the json parse with unicode.  Is there any way around this with Angular, or do you have to modify your python to leave out the unicode character?

I'm using angular 1.3

> angular.js:11607 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
>   I can see it's failing at JSON.parse

data looks like this coming back from python service:

> {u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'rows': [{u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'brave'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'forfeits'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'holding'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'profession'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'Condemn'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u"fear'st"}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'answered'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'religion'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u"You're"}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'deputy'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'heed'}]},
>   {u'f': [{u'v': u'generation'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'Boldly'}]}, {u'f':
>   [{u'v': u"'"}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'told'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'answer'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'regard'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'Touching'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'meet'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u"o'er"}]},
>   {u'f': [{u'v': u'dawn'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'authorities'}]}, {u'f':
>   [{u'v': u'Mended'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'quality'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'lusty'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'forbid'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'instruments'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'A'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':
>   u'dreadfully'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'accordingly'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v':

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Angular has a problem with the json parse with unicode.

No, the problem is that the service literally returns

```
{u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', ...}`.
```

Which is not JSON. That `u` right after the `{` is invalid (which is what the error tells you). Simple proof:

```
> JSON.parse("{u'foo': 'bar'}");
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

Whatever you do, you are not creating the response properly. Use [**`json.dumps`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

---

Given the fact that the linked tutorial claims the response is JSON is an indicator that it may not be a good tutorial.

However, if you continue to follow the tutorial, you will see that the return proper JSON in the [third part](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/data-visualization-app-using-gae-python-d3js-and-google-bigquery-part-3--cms-22629).

Comment: I tried to consume the data in the tutorial I was reading.  Should have looked ahead to see that they modified the output to be JSON.  Wondered if there was some "magic" parser in angular js, but thanks for stating there isn't.